# HTML-CSS esconder e mostrar submenu não funciona

Tags: html, css, css-hover

Estou tentando fazer um menu que abre ao passar o mouse abre o submenu correspondente. No caso, o menu "blusas e camisas" deveria estar com o seu submenu fechado, abrindo apenas ao passar o mouse sobre ele para mostrar as opções manga curta e as demais. porém, quando abro a tela no meu navegador, o submenu já aparece logo abaixo como se estivesse ali estático, o que me faz supor que o CSS esteja falhando nesta função

No css tenho

```
.menu-departamentos li ul { 
    display: none; 
} 
.menu-departamentos li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

e no HTMl eu tenho

```
<section class="menu-departamentos"> 
<h2>Departamentos</h2>
<nav> 
<ul> 
<li><a href="#">Blusas e Camisas</a></li> 
<ul> 
    <li><a href="#">Manga curta</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Manga comprida</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Camisa social</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Camisa casual</a></li> 
</ul> 
<li><a href="#">Calças</a></li> 
<li><a href="#">Acessórios</a></li> 
</ul> 
</nav> 
</section>
```

Comment: Rafael seu problema na verdade era no HTML e não no CSS, Executa o Snippet da minha resposta que agora ele funciona direitinho com Hover nos subintes etc.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou já

Answer (score 1):

Precisei fazer uma correção no `HTML`, você estava fechando a `<li>` antes de colocar a `<ul>` dentro. No seu caso que é uma *sub-lista* o correto é fazer dessa forma.

```
<ul>
<li><a></a>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</li><!-- fecha o LI aqui -->
</ul>
```

Veja no código abaixo

```css
.menu-departamentos li ul { 
  display: none; 
} 
.menu-departamentos li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="menu-departamentos"> 
    <h2>Departamentos</h2>
    <nav> 
      <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">Blusas e Camisas</a> 
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="#">Manga curta</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Manga comprida</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Camisa social</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Camisa casual</a></li> 
        </ul> 
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Calças</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Acessórios</a></li> 
      </ul> 
    </nav> 
</section>
```